# Does the App Engine Conversion API for HTML to PDF support canvas or SVG?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-conversion

I am trying to figure out the best way of allowing my users to create a family tree chart, view it on screen and then to be able to create a PDF of it.
I am considering using ReportLab for the PDF generation, however then I have to have separate display and PDF code.

So I was wondering if the Conversion API would be able to handle HTML with canvas (and therefore Javascript), I am guessing probably not, but I thought I would ask.

I am a little more hopeful about it being able to generate HTML with SVG since it can be rendered without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could export the canvas to an image (`toDataURL`) after the user creates or modifies the chart, and swap the two when calling the Conversion API.